# Does Dropwizard support Server Sent Event?

Tags: rest, dropwizard

Seems like Jersey 2.0 has support for SSE, but Dropwizard is using Jersey 1.x . Does Dropwizard have any support for SSE ?

Comment: I am trying to get this to work like this: Register a servlet in the service initializer and then override the doGet to write to a Stream. Or just add a resource with HttpServletResponse as one of the context parameters and write to that.

Comment: `@Override
 public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)  
 {
  try
     {
         System.out.println("SSE Demo");
         response.setContentType("text/event-stream");

         PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
         int i=0;
         while(true)
         {

             i++;
             pw.write("event: server-time\n\n");  //take note of the 2 \n 's, also on the next line.
             pw.write("data: "+ i + "\n\n");
             System.out.println("Data Sent!!!"+i);
         }

     }catch(Exception e){
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
 }`

Comment: But I am not able to get this to work. This is my client
`<html>
<body onload ="registerSSE()" >
    <script>
function registerSSE()
{
alert('test 1');
var source = new EventSource('http://localhost:7000/business/changes');  
alert('Test2');
source.onmessage=function(event)
{
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML+=event.data + "<br />";
            };

            /*source.addEventListener('server-time',function (e){
                alert('ea');
            },true);*/
        }
    </script>
    <output id ="result"></output>
</body>
</html>`

Comment: @user1710833 You might want to add those code snippets into your question to promote alternative approaches - having them crammed into a comment makes them hard to read.